# How can i find the length of this Json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to find the length of this JSON object so any one tell me how can i get length of the JSON object...means i want to know how many data this json object contain.

```
var ddData = [{ "01":"United States",
                "02":"United Kingdom",
                "03":"Aruba",
                "04":"United Kingdom",
                "05":"Aruba",
                "06":"Bahrain",
                "07":"United Kingdom",
                "08":"Algeria",
                "09":"Andorra",
                "10":"American Samoa",
                "11":"United States"
             }]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use `Object.keys` method to get the object keys.
Since ddData is an `array`, and the first index contains an object, you could do this :

```
Object.keys(ddData[0]).length;
```

However, `Object.keys` does not work on [old browsers](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/).

For that, you could iterate through the object and increment a variable to get the length of that object.

```
var count = 0;
for(var i in ddData[0]) {
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `Object.key`s that will return the length of specified collection.[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LzSZC/1/).

(Browser support from [here](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/))
(Doc on Object.keys [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), includes method you can add to non-ECMA5 browsers)

Answer (score 2):

you can simply do this instead of calling functions

```
var key, count = 0;
for(key in ddData[0]) {
  count++;
}

console.log(count + " is size of the json");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var length=0;
for(attr in ddData[0]){
     length++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var json = JSON.parse(ddData);
for(i=0;i<json.length;i++)
{
alert(json[i].length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Now i got the answer....

```
var Data = { "01":"United States",
            "02":"United Kingdom",
            "03":"Aruba",
            "04":"United Kingdom",
            "05":"Aruba",
            "06":"Bahrain",
            "07":"United Kingdom",
            "08":"Algeria",
            "09":"Andorra",
            "10":"American Samoa",
            "11":"United States"
         }

var count = 0;
for(x in Data){
    count++;
}
console.log('cnt',count)
```